# Debugging asp.net web forms app throws InvalidOperationException In VS 2013

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2013

A strange problem started happening today.
Whenever I try to evaluate an SqlDataReader result it shows that there is no data available but if I don't try it, it works as expected.

For example, having this query:

```
using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            obj.Id = int.Parse(reader[0].ToString());
                        }
                    }
```

Works ok if I don't evaluate the reader (see below image with what i mean).

[image]

Can anyone help me debug this? I'm using visual studio 2013 Profesional.
Please be aware that there is data in the DB and everything works ok if I don't evaluate the reader. The cmd string is `Select * from MyTable`

Answer (score 0):

It seems like, during your evaluation step, you are using the returned record. Your `reader.Read()` would continue from to the next record.

For this to be true, I make the assumption that you are looking for only 1 return value.
If you are, you can use the `cmd.ExecuteScalar()` command to get a single value returned without the need of a reader at all.

```
obj.id = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

You will probably need to cast your result to the correct type like:

```
obj.id = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
```

or

```
obj.id = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
```

If you wish to test the fact that your evaluator is consuming your `.Read()` results, have something return 2 values, and evaluate for the first one. You should receive the second value afterwards.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that this reads more values, around 100 values.

Comment: @Zippy, so it breaks all of them even if you evaluate one? It may be taking the entire reader element into the evaluator and returning nothing.

Comment: If I evaluate the reader at `cmd.ExecuteReader` it shows that it has 100 rows, with values as expected...